# How to stop shift from affecting other instances of an array

Tags: ruby

I need to shift through an array and keep a copy of the original array for future.

I tried creating another variable using `a = b`, but both are affected when I shift `a`.

```
rb(main):001:0> a = [1,2,3,4,5]

# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

irb(main):002:0> b = a

# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

irb(main):003:0> c = a.shift

# => 1

irb(main):004:0> a

# => [2, 3, 4, 5]

irb(main):005:0> b

# => [2, 3, 4, 5]

irb(main):006:0> c

# => 1
```

Is there a way to keep this from happening?

Comment: "how do I stop the ruby shift method from affecting other instances of an array" – They *aren't* "other instances of an array". There is only one array in your code. You are calling three different names, but that doesn't change anything. Your mother probably calls you a different name than your boss does, still, if you cut your hair, *both* of them will see that you cut your hair, no matter what name they call you.

Comment: @JörgWMittag kinda snarky, but funny and explains it perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby it's important to remember variables are *object references* which behave a lot like pointers, so `b = a` does not make a copy, it is another reference to the same object.

To make a copy you must be explicit and use `dup` or `clone` to achieve this:

```
b = a.dup
```

If you're ever confused by Ruby's behaviour, stop and look at the objects you're dealing with:

```
a = [ 1 ]
b = a
a.object_id == b.object_id
# => true
```

They're exactly the same object, but when cloned:

```
b = a.dup
a.object_id == b.object_id
# => false
```

Now they're independent, at least on the top-level.

Note that this comes with some caveats, as this is only a *shallow copy*:

```
a = [ [ 1 ] ]
b = a.dup

b[0].object_id == a[0].object_id
# => true
```

This is where `deep_clone` tools come in handy if you need a complete clone, something available from various gems but most popularly ActiveSupport from Rails.

One thing you'll find in Ruby is it tends to steer towards a more *functional* style, as in if you wanted to strip an element from `a` and avoid mangling `b`:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
b = a

a = a.drop(1)
# => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Where `drop` skips over the first *N* entries and returns the rest as a copy:

```
b
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```